# IndexError: list index out of range, in CSV but if I print row[index] it works

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV and the following code:

```
with open("results.csv", 'rt', encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, skipinitialspace=True, escapechar='\\')
    A = 0
    for row in reader:
        if row[4] in validclubs and "A" in row[0]:
            A = A + 1
print(A)
```

but it returns:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
if row[4] in validclubs and "A" in row[0]:
IndexError: list index out of range`.

However if I change my code to:

```
with open("results.csv", 'rt', encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, skipinitialspace=True, escapechar='\\')
    A = 0
    for row in reader:
        if row[4] in validclubs and "A" in row[0]:
            print(A)
```

It will `print(A)` correctly and return the same error. Therefore, it's not out of range as it prints properly. So what is causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the error is *not* caused by the first time the condition is met, but rather by the second (or later) time. Therefore, you manage to print 'A' once, and only then encounter the error.

Comment: The problem was a line at the end of the file contained just ' and caused index error